# image.getCropRect() return wrong crop rectangle

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-camera2, android-camerax

I want to crop image from imageAnalysis in same ratio as a viewportsize:

```
    ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setTargetResolution(new Size(1200, 1200))
            .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
            .setOutputImageFormat(ImageAnalysis.OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_RGBA_8888)
            .build();

    // ViewPort
    Rational aspectRatio = new Rational(cameraView.getWidth(), cameraView.getHeight());
    ViewPort viewPort = new ViewPort.Builder(aspectRatio, preview.getTargetRotation()).setScaleType(ViewPort.FILL_CENTER).build();

    UseCaseGroup useCaseGroup = new UseCaseGroup.Builder()
            .addUseCase(preview)
            .addUseCase(imageAnalysis)
            .setViewPort(viewPort)
            .build();
```

ImageProxy result size:

```
            height= image.getWidth(); //1280
            width= image.getHeight(); // 960
            сrop_rect = image.getCropRect();
```

Viewport size

```
            heightPreview = binding.cameraView.getHeight(); //2274
            widthPreview = binding.cameraView.getWidth(); //1080
```

proxyImage size: 1280x960
viewport size: 2274x1080

I call `image.getCropRect();`

And we got the clipping rectangle:

```
Rect(
    bottom = 784,
    left = 0,
    right = 1280,
    top = 176
)
```

The red area is the clipping coordinates.

[image]

**But these are not the right coords!**

Right coords is (I calculated it on paper ):

```
Rect(
    bottom = 606,
    left = 0,
    right = 1280,
    top = 177
)
```

And right red border cropping area.

[image]

(The coords and example images may be in the wrong rotation)

Where I did a mistake to calc a right cropping coords?
What exactly does getCropRect() return?

Comment: `Rect(0, 176 ,1280, 784)` represents `Rect(left, top, right, bottom)`, right?

Comment: bottom = 784
left = 0
right = 1280
top = 176

Comment: Then that's working as intended. height: 784-176 = 608. width: 1280-0 = 1280. Aspect ratio: 608/1280=0.475, which is the same as you defined in ViewPort (1080/2274)

Comment: thnx. But why should we do 784-176? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image#getCropRect()
"Get the crop rectangle associated with this frame."
Returned reactangle is not has 0.475. I cant understand logic

Comment: height = bottom - top. width = right - left. width/height is the aspect ratio.